# listening on a socket in the background

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have a Server class, which has a function to listen on a socket in the background, and add clients to a vector of clients.
The function is

```
int Server::accept_clients(int *res) {
    auto accept_clients_thread = [this](int *running) {
        std::cout << "started accepting clients" << std::endl;
        while (!this->socket_accept()) {
        }
        std::cout << "stopped accepting clients" << std::endl;
        *running = 0;
    };
    std::thread t(accept_clients_thread, res);
    t.detach();

    return 0;
}
```

and the `socket_accept` function is

```
int Server::socket_accept() {
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    unsigned int len = sizeof(addr);

    fd = accept(_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len);

    Client_ctx client;
    client.init(fd, &addr);

    _clients.push_back(client);
    std::cout << "accepted client" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work, but it looks like a quick and dirty solution.
What would be the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: If you can afford one thread per listening socket, this is how you do it. If not, you collect all sockets and poll them repeatedly.

Comment: If there is no obvious problem with your code and you just want a review or general tips, the question might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Questions here require a clear problem statement with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The shown code has multiple instances of guaranteed and likely undefined behavior due to thread synchronization failures. It is clear that `running` is accessed by multiple threads, but is completely unsynchronized. Additionally, nothing seems to guarantee that the execution thread that captured `this` will get terminated before its object gets destroyed.